# how to call WinApi function from C++?

Tags: c++, dll

In C# I have such P/Invoke declaration:

```
    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int NtQueryTimerResolution(out int MinimumResolution, out int MaximumResolution, out int ActualResolution);
```

I can use function just by name then: `NtQueryTimerResolution(out min, out max, out current);`

I'm rewriting my code to C++. How to make the same import in C++?

Comment: It's undocumented, so it's not reliable and not in any distributed headers, so you'll have to resort to ye olde `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: i think I just found what i'm looking for https://code.google.com/p/bitspersampleconv2/source/browse/trunk/TimerTest2/main.cpp?r=2813

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the function QueryPerformanceCounter()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx